# JBehave dependencies not available in central maven repo?

Tags: java, maven, jbehave

I'm having more difficulty than I expected accessing jbehave dependecies from the maven central repo (search.maven.org).

I'm trying to grab

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jbehave%7Cjbehave-distribution%7C4.0%7Cpom

using the method I normally use, which is to paste the dependency code into the dependencies section of my pom. Is anyone else having this trouble?

And of course.. the error message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXXX: Failure to find org.jbehave:jbehave:jar:4.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I have tried forcing dependencies already using **mvn clean install -U** but to no avail.

And by popular request (it probably needs some tidying up) but here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXXXX</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XXXXX</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Neo4j Test Scoped Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- The part of spring social that provides serialised data for persisting 
            to a database. To quote from http://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/serviceprovider.html 
            "Finally, the internal state of a connection can be captured for transfer 
            between layers of your application by calling createData(). This could be 
            used to persist the connection in a database, or serialize it over the network." 
            In reality, we transfer more than the connection. Because of how dependant 
            the Connection object api is on the rest of spring social, we must bring 
            in the whole dependency. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasypt</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Code coverage mojo for EmmaEcl -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which 
                        is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</destFile>
                            <!-- Sets the name of the property containing the settings for JaCoCo 
                                runtime agent. -->
                            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Ensures that the code coverage report for unit tests is created 
                        after unit tests have been run. -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Sets the path to the file which contains the execution data. -->
                            <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-ut.exec</dataFile>
                            <!-- Sets the output directory for the code coverage report. -->
                            <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Sets the VM argument line used when unit tests are run. -->
                    <argLine>${surefireArgLine}</argLine>
                    <!-- Skips unit tests if the value of skip.unit.tests property is true -->
                    <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
                    <!-- Excludes integration tests when unit tests are run. -->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/IT*.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.myproject.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: You need to post your pom file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I felt I had to re-answer this because the following achieves the goal whereas neither of the other answers do. Below is an example pom that works for JBehave. jbehave-core seems essential. I am optionally using jbehave-gherkin which allows me to write my user scenarios in gherkin (seems like a cross framework language) rather than JBehave's own user scenario language.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp.bdd</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-bdd</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>BDD Test POM Example</name>
    <description>BDD Tests</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbehave-gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set up a jar dependency (that is the default type) to `org.jbehave:jbehave` but that artifact does only have an artifact of type `pom` published.

The dependency should look like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbehave</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as it got the dependency working for me. Thank you :) In terms of JBehave itself, it didn't seem to come with what I needed so I wonder if I was trying to download the wrong dependency! I'll have another look at it in the next few days and see where I get to.

Answer (score 0):

Instead:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

include this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jbehave</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbehave-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and check if maven now resolves yours problem.

Comment: Thank you. I tried already. Result is: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project XXXXX: Could not resolved
ependencies for project com.myproject:0.0.1-
SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jbehave:jbehave-dis
tribution:jar:4.0, com.google.gdata:gdata-java-client:jar:1.40.0.atlassian-2: Fa
ilure to find org.jbehave:jbehave-distribution:jar:4.0 in http://repo.maven.apac
he.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattem
pted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [
Help 1]
[ERROR]. Does it work for you?

Comment: There are 2 possibilites. First is to clear jbehave directories in your local repo and use mvn clean install. Second: use mvn clean install -U. Give a shot which one helps you.